# How to check if an ID present in year A is present in years A+1 and A+3

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with IDs, years, career_ID, Type (being "new" or "old"), year+1 and year+3, and I need to figure a way to add two extra columns: is_present_in_year_A+1 and is_present_in_year_A+3, but only for IDs with Type = New.

Thanks in advance.

I tried creating a function to check the presence of the ID:

```
check_presence_1 <- function(BBDD2, ANNO) {
  BBDD2 %>%
    select(ID) %>%
    filter(ANNO == ANNO_RET_1) %>%
    mutate(present = TRUE)
}
```

(and again changing 1s for 3s)

and then adding the columns according to this suggested code, which gives me numbers that make no sense

```
result_data <- BBDD2 %>%
  filter(TIPO_ALU == "NUEVO") %>%
  mutate(first_year = min(ANNO), 
    present_x1 = ifelse(ID %in% check_presence_1(filter(., ANNO > first_year), ANNO_RET_1)$ID, TRUE, FALSE),
    present_x3 = ifelse(ID %in% check_presence_3(filter(., ANNO > first_year), ANNO_RET_3)$ID, TRUE, FALSE))
```

those codes came from chatGPT, as it's been a long while since I last used R and wanted to check if it was useful.

EDIT: changed BBDD to BBDD2 to clean some columns I don't need for this particular problem.
Also here is a sample of the data:

```
structure(list(ANNO = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012), ID = c(14L, 
37L, 76L, 100L, 112L), TIPO_ALU = c("NUEVO", "NUEVO", "NUEVO", 
"NUEVO", "NUEVO"), COD_CARRERA = c("I70S1C751J1V1", "I70S1C756J2V1", 
"I70S1C603J1V1", "I70S1C779J2V1", "I70S1C611J1V1"), ANNO_RET_1 = c(2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013), ANNO_RET_3 = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

the idea being to obtain two new columns in the form: PRESENT_ANNO+1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0), PRESENT_ANNO+3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Please provide an example of your data to make your code reproducible.

Comment: Also please include your desired result with the sample input to make sure everything is clear. 5-10 rows of sample data should be plenty. You can make copy/pasteable sample data with `dput()`, as in `dput(BBDD[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows.

Comment: added a sample of the data and desired result

Comment: Where should the variation come from? Only colums `COD_CARRERA` and `ID` vary in your samle data. How do you compute the new columns?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this (and not native english speaker), ANNO goes from 2012 to 2022, TIPO_ALU is either "NUEVO" or "ANTIGUO", ANNO_RET_1 is always ANNO+1 and ANNO_RET_3 is always ANNO+3

the dataframe is exactly 435058 lines long so I didn't know how to present it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without bigger dataset (that shows variation in `ANNO` and `TIPO_ALU`), but I think you're looking to do this:

```
library(dplyr)

BBDD2 |> 
  mutate(
    `is_present_in_year_A+1` = ((ANNO + 1) %in% ANNO) & (TIPO_ALU == "NUEVO"),
    `is_present_in_year_A+3` = ((ANNO + 3) %in% ANNO) & (TIPO_ALU == "NUEVO"), 
    .by = ID
  )
```

Comment: I think it follows the idea, but the result is wrong (I know that the number of ID's with "NUEVO" in 2018, with COD_CARRERA = I70S1C21J1V1 that should have "TRUE" in `is_present_in_year_A+1` should be 521. but with this there's only 6, if you give me a moment I can try and give you a bigger example of the dataset

Comment: (ANNO = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014), ID = c(14L, 37L, 76L, 14L, 37L, 76L, 14L, 37L, 100L), TIPO_ALU = c("NUEVO", "NUEVO", "ANTIGUO", 
"NUEVO", "NUEVO", "ANTIGUO", "NUEVO", "NUEVO", "NUEVO"), COD_CARRERA = c("I70S1C21J1V1", "I70S1C21J1V1", "I70S1C603J1V1", "I70S1C21J1V1", "I70S1C21J1V1", "I70S1C603J1V1", "I70S1C21J1V1", "I70S1C21J1V1", "I70S1C705J1V1"), ANNO_RET_1 = c(2013, 2013, 0, 2014, 2014, 0, 2015, 2015, 2015), ANNO_RET_3 = c(2015, 2015, 0, 2016, 2016, 0, 2017, 2017, 2017))

Comment: In that example, there are 3 IDs in 2012, two of them are "nuevo" and the other is "antiguo", the "antiguo" will not be touched, the idea is first know when will be the years we will want to know if each "nuevo" ID is still present (being "antiguo" in those future years of course),and then calculate if they are indeed still present in those years.
¿is that more understandable?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, the code that did it was the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
BBDD <- read_excel("C:/Users/tomas.daneri.SC/Desktop/Retención/MATRICULA_SIES_2012-2022_FORMATEADO.xlsx")
BBDD$COD_RET_1 <- 0
BBDD$ANNO_RET_1 <- 0
BBDD$COD_RET_1 <- ifelse(BBDD$TIPO_ALU == "NUEVO", paste(BBDD$ANNO,BBDD$COD_CARRERA), 0)
BBDD$ANNO_RET_1 <- ifelse(BBDD$TIPO_ALU == "NUEVO", BBDD$ANIO_ING_CARRERA_ACTUAL+1, 0)
BBDD$ANNO_RET_3 <- ifelse(BBDD$TIPO_ALU == "NUEVO", BBDD$ANIO_ING_CARRERA_ACTUAL+3, 0)

BBDD <- BBDD %>%
  group_by(RUT) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(ID = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup()

result_data <- BBDD %>%
  mutate(first_year = min(ANNO), 
         present_x1 = ID %in% ANNO == ANNO+1,
         present_x3 = ID %in% ANNO == ANNO+3)

BBDD2 <- result_data %>%
  select(ANNO, COD_CARRERA, TIPO_ALU, ID)

BBDD2 <- BBDD2 %>%
  mutate(
    present_x1 = ((ANNO + 1) %in% ANNO),
    present_x3 = ((ANNO + 3) %in% ANNO),
    .by = ID
  )

BBDD2$present_x1 <- as.integer(as.logical(BBDD2$present_x1))
BBDD2$present_x3 <- as.integer(as.logical(BBDD2$present_x3))

carreras <- BBDD2 %>%
  filter(TIPO_ALU == "NUEVO") %>%
  group_by(COD_CARRERA, ANNO) %>%
  summarize(num_present_x1 = sum(present_x1),
            num_present_x3 = sum(present_x3))
print(carreras)
write_xlsx(BBDD2, "C:/Users/tomas.daneri.SC/Desktop/Retención/BBDD2.xlsx")
```

hurrah